# Display NCover coverage report inside TeamCity

Tags: continuous-integration, teamcity, code-coverage, ncover

I am running NCover 3, with TeamCity 7. TeamCity is kicking off the cover process and I can find the fullcoveragereport.html in my file directory for the build, however TeamCity is not creating a tab for the coverage.

I cant view this Ncover fullcoveragereport.html inside of TeamCity. I think it has to do with my report tab settings, under the start page section, it says 
"Relative path from the root of build's artifacts to a start page of the generated report.
To reference a file from an archive, use the [path-to-archive]![relative-path] syntax." Is this in reference to the build server machine, that is, I want to point it from the .buildserver folder to the coverage.zip folder?

I now get a "This is an autogenerated index file (there was no index.html found in the generated report)." in the coverage tab, I think I am getting close...

Any ideas, or things I might have missed?

Comment: actually none of my reports show up in teamcity.

Comment: http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD7/Manually+Configuring+Reporting+Coverage i think this link might be useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it seems as though using many missread the documentation and put in // 
as the parameter . They also put in FullCoverageReport:Html:{teamcity.report.path}.

In actuality it should be one entire string with the or in there which throws some people off.

```
//or FullCoverageReport:Html:{teamcity.report.path}
```

In this scenario (im not 100% sure why), this still didnt work. I was pleased to find out that

```
//or Summary:Html:{teamcity.report.path}
```

Will work. Its not as verbose as the full NCover report but it beats an empty index.html file.

- it turns out there is an issue with the FullReport with NCover 3 and TeamCity 7 , read more about it below. 
  http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-20635

I'm going to try some of the other reporting commands (see below) and see if i can make an ad-hoc FullCoverageReport to suffice. 
http://docs.ncover.com/kb/reports-available-in-ncover-classic-and-ncover-complete/